# Filter a list of Web elements by using Xpath Selenium/C#

Tags: c#, xpath

I am locating all of the option tag elements, what I want to do when I search for them is to filter them by saying give me all the option tag elements that are not disabled.

```
<option value="2015-09-01">September 2015</option>
<option disabled="disabled" value="2015-08-01">August 2015</option>
```

In this case I would like to have in my list only the first element since it's not disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following XPath to get `option` elements that doesn't have attribute `disabled` :

```
//option[not(@disabled)]
```